# Dynamic height for table view cells with images asynchronous loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom cell with dynamic height inside a XIB file which shows a post with a message and an image. Because the image will be loaded asynchronously from my API the aspect ratio of the image will be send with the resource. Inside the `updateConstraints` method the aspect ratio constraint with the proper multiplier will be set.

The XIB file:

[image: My XIB file]

The cell class:

```
//
//  PostTableViewCell.swift
//  Lome
//
//  Created by Tobias Feistmantl on 10/09/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Tobias Feistmantl. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire

class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileImageView: TFImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usersNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfileButton: TFCellButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timestampLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var constraintBetweenMessageLabelAndPostImageView: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var post: Post! {
        didSet {
            post.author.profileImage(version: .Thumbnail) { image, _ in
                self.userProfileImageView.image = image
            }

            if let name = post.author.fullName {
                usersNameLabel.text = name
                usernameLabel.text = post.author.username
            } else {
                usersNameLabel.text = post.author.username
                usernameLabel.hidden = true
            }

            if let attributedMessage = post.attributedMessage {
                messageLabel.attributedText = attributedMessage
                messageLabel.hidden = false
                constraintBetweenMessageLabelAndPostImageView.constant = 15
            } else {
                messageLabel.hidden = true
                messageLabel.attributedText = nil
                constraintBetweenMessageLabelAndPostImageView.constant = 0
            }

            post.image { image, _ in
                if let image = image {
                    self.postImageView.image = image
                    self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                }
            }

            timestampLabel.text = "Posted \(post.createdAt.timeAgoSinceNow())"
            distanceLabel.text = post.distanceText
            likeCountLabel.text = "\(post.likesCount) Likes"
            likeButton.setImage(post.likeButtonImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if let aspectRatio = post.imageAspectRatio {
            postImageAspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: postImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: CGFloat(aspectRatio), constant: 0)
        }

        super.updateConstraints()
    }

    func setupUserProfileButton(indexPath: NSIndexPath, viewController: UIViewController) {
        userProfileButton.indexPath = indexPath
        userProfileButton.addTarget(viewController, action: "userProfileButtonDidTouch:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    var postImageAspectConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? {
        didSet {
            if let oldValue = oldValue {
                postImageView.removeConstraint(oldValue)
            }
            if let postImageAspectConstraint = postImageAspectConstraint {
                postImageView.addConstraint(postImageAspectConstraint)
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        postImageAspectConstraint = nil
    }

}
```

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

    cell.post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.setupUserProfileButton(indexPath, viewController: self)

    return cell
}
```

On the app start everything works as expected, but if I scoll a little bit, the contraints begin to break and the aspect of the images aren't right anymore or some other strange things like below:

[image: Broken cell]

Errors:

```
2015-09-28 11:58:27.546 Lome[32812:528936] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a008bf6f0 V:[Lome.TFImageView:0x7f8a008bf470(35)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f89f9fbc490 V:|-(15)-[Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831520 Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0.top == Lome.TFImageView:0x7f8a008bf470.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a008315c0 Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0.bottom == Lome.TFImageView:0x7f8a008bf470.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831750 V:[Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0]-(18)-[UILabel:0x7f8a008806d0'Water']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831840 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831890 H:[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a008318e0 V:[UILabel:0x7f8a008806d0'Water']-(15)-[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831930 V:[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]-(20)-[UILabel:0x7f8a00830b90'0 Likes']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831980 V:[UILabel:0x7f8a00830b90'0 Likes']-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00860870 UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.width == 0.6672*UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a0084e990 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270(611)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a0084f930 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a008bf6f0 V:[Lome.TFImageView:0x7f8a008bf470(35)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-28 11:58:27.547 Lome[32812:528936] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f89f9fbc490 V:|-(15)-[Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831520 Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0.top == Lome.TFImageView:0x7f8a008bf470.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a008315c0 Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0.bottom == Lome.TFImageView:0x7f8a008bf470.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831750 V:[Lome.TFCellButton:0x7f8a0087fde0]-(18)-[UILabel:0x7f8a008806d0'Water']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831840 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831890 H:[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a008318e0 V:[UILabel:0x7f8a008806d0'Water']-(15)-[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831930 V:[UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910]-(20)-[UILabel:0x7f8a00830b90'0 Likes']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00831980 V:[UILabel:0x7f8a00830b90'0 Likes']-(20)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00860870 UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.width == 0.6672*UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a0084e990 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270(611)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a0084f930 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a008bf270(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00860870 UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.width == 0.6672*UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.height>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I think it has something to do with the reusing of the cells but as you can see the constraint will be removed in the `prepareForReuse` method.

I'm currently pretty frustrated because I'm trying to solve this problem since a few days and don't find a solution.

I hope somebody have a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to set the height of your image view rather than the width in `updateConstraints:`. From a first look, this seems to be an ambiguous situation as you already have pinned the `ImageView` with horizontal layouts with 0 spacing and then trying to change the width as per height.

Comment: This is an aspect ratio constraint not a width constraint. The height of UIImageView is 0.6672 times bigger than the width. However if i set a fixed height in IB and don't add this aspect ratio constraint it works but I have always the same height and a false aspect ratio because every image is different.

Comment: I know that you have applied aspect ratio constraint. I think you misunderstood what i was referring to. In your aspect ration constraint, the `first item` is `width`. That means constraint will attempt to make the changes in `width` not to `height` of that view. So if you reverse the first and second item from it and inverse the aspect ratio in multiplier argument, you will have the same constraint but with a varying height as per image aspect ratio.

Comment: THANK YOU!! It solved my problem! Write this comment as answer and i will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to override updateLayoutConstraints! This saved my life!!! Nice code btw :-)

Comment: did you still had to call beingupdates on tableview? how did you made sure the tableview updated accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by 2 conflicting constraints applied to the `ImageView`. If you look at the debugger output

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8a00860870 UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.width == 0.6672*UIImageView:0x7f8a00830910.height>
```

You already have horizontal constraint to the `ImageView` pinned to the `superview` with 0 spacing.

Now while updating the aspect ratio constraint you are trying to set the `width`(by keeping width as first item) of `ImageView` as a ratio of it's `height`, which will lead to conflict with it's Leading/Trailing constraint. 
You need to set the height of this ImageView by interchanging the first and second items and inverting the aspect ratio factor.

```
postImageAspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: postImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: postImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1/CGFloat(aspectRatio), constant: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the image height, you should
update your array, e.g. rowHeightArray, which keeps track of all the rowHeights, e.g.

```
[rowHeightArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:imageHeight]];
```

Then call

```
[aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:YES];
```

It will call

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [[rowHeightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];   
}
```

where you return the object at the indexPath with the row height.

Comment: The row height of the cells is set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Through the auto layout constraints the row height will be automatically defined. The problem I have is that the aspect ratio constraint gets broken after scrolling up and down.

Comment: Did you try to add a constraint to the UIImageView ? Have the images the same width and height or at least the same ratio? If not, you should remove the previous constraint and add a new constraint or check the ScaleToFit or ScaleToFill... I do not really know the way you do.

Answer (score 0):

To remove constraints, check:

```
[aView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[aView removeConstraints:view.constraints];
```

or

```
for(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in aView.constraints){
    [aView.view removeConstraint:constraint];
}
```